# Sort text and numbers in Excel so the numbers sort properly?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I've created an inventory of my watercolor paints. Paints use pigment categories and pigment numbers. For example, blue pigments all start with the pigment category PB (pigment blue), followed by the pigment number, such as 15:6. Putting the pigment category and the pigment number together, that color is PB15:6.

The letters and numbers are important; a paint manufacturer may call a blue "Cerulean," but if the pigment number of PB15, then you know it's phthalocyanine blue.

In my inventory, I have one row per tube of paint, with all manner of info about the paint by column, including the pigment number. I want to sort by pigment number, but PR 122 sorts before PR 88, which sorts before PR 9. I've tried it with and without the spaces (PR9, PR 9), but the sort still doesn't work the way I want.

[image]

The only solution I can think of is to put the pigment category in a separate column from the numbers; i.e., one column for the category, another for the pigment number, but that's annoying and a lot of work. Especially for paints that are combinations of several pigments; I have one column per pigment up to three pigments. If a paint uses more than three pigments, I put pigment 4+ in the third column. (I prefer single pigments, but I have a few mixes.)

Does anyone have a solution for this specific sorting problem?

Comment: I generally work around this kind of issues simply by using leading zeros. I.e. PR 88 becomes PR 088. In this kind of situation I take the annoying road as I've found that the extra initial work makes the usage a lot more versatile.

Comment: Thank you, Peregrino. I thought about that solution, but the pigment numbers don't include zeroes. I sometimes share my workbook with others who also want to inventory their paints without having to create a workbook from scratch. They're generally new to pigment numbers. I don't want to mislead or confuse them.

Comment: Sorry I can't give a better answer, don't have any version of Excel available. The only solution I can think for that problem is adding a clear instruction about using leading zeros, with an example... luckily there are members of the community whose Excel skills _far_ exceed mine :-)

Comment: Interesting question/challenge. Is there a way for you to convert your pigment (combination) to a single sRGB value or something like that? If no, then I would think power query or VBA is necessary. As you said you share your workbook, it could be problematic.

Comment: There are several ways of solving this problem, but your question is not clear. Your table shows three columns of pigments, but your textual question references `PB15:6`. What columns are you expecting to sort? Please show an example of an unsorted table, and, if there are multiple columns to sort, how you expect it to be sorted. Also, will this be being used on a single computer?  Or on multiple computers? If you do not want helper columns on your worksheet, you will need to use VBA, Power Query, or possibly a Custom Sort LIst.